# Change template copy with po/mo files

Tags: translation

I just got my hands on a WordPress site and i'm trying to edit some words from a theme login template, so I went to **cPanel** to check how the theme templates handle the copy and I found the `pt_PT.po` with the words I was looking for.

After understanding a bit better how `.po` and `.mo` files work, I installed LOCO translations plugin to edit those files and I found the phrases I was looking for, edited and saved them.

I went back to cPanel and the `.po` file was changed with the copy I wanted, but there were no changes to the site, even after cleaning the cache. `.mo` file was also changed because had the same "last modified" timestamp.

I read in other answers that adding `define('WPLANG', 'your_language');` to the `wp-config.php` would do the trick, but since this site already has the translations from English to Portuguese online it didn't make sense to me to add that line.

I'm I wrong and I still need to add it or is it something else?

Thanks!

Comment: In WordPress 4.0 and above, you should set your site's language via this page: *Settings > General > Site Language* and no need to define the `WPLANG`.

Comment: There are dozens of possible causes. Provide a download link to the theme's source code and an example string you can't get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had a similar question posted some time ago: [why is translation not working on theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309065/why-is-translation-not-working-on-theme)

it might be the solution to put your translation files into the right location (languages directory in `wp-content/languages/themes/`) and prefix them with the theme name like `themename-pt_PT.po`